# GSON return Object how to parse?

Tags: java, android, json, object, gson

My Web API returns a OBJECT and not an Array...

```
JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 13 path $.product
```

I will get the value like this

```
private List<ProductDetailsSimple> product;
public List<ProductDetails> getProduct() {
            return product;
        }
```

This ist not working!

The follow code is working but it retrieve a object like "key=value,key=value,key=value"
So i cannot fetch the datas from the Object....

```
public Object getProduct() {

       if( product instanceof Map ) {
            Map map = (Map)product; 
           String title = (String)map.get("title");
            String image = (String)map.get("featured_src");
            Log.e("TESTLOG",title.toString());

       }
```

Here is my ProductDetailsSimple.java

```
public class ProductDetailsSimple {


private String id;
private String title;
private String created_at;


public String getId() {
    return id;

}

public String getName() {
    return title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return created_at;
}
```

}

Also i can fetch the Object but i can parse from the object values by keys...
How can i do that?

API OUTPUT JSON
http://copy-cat.at/api/?act=getProduct&product_id=590

Many thanks i going crazy.... xD

**EDIT:**

```
    package com.learn2crack.listviewjson;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.learn2crack.listviewjson.model.ResponseProduct;
import com.learn2crack.listviewjson.model.ProductDetails;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 21.10.2017.
 */


    public class LoadJSONTaskProduct extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ResponseProduct> {

        public LoadJSONTaskProduct(com.learn2crack.listviewjson.LoadJSONTaskProduct.Listener listener) {

            mListener = listener;
        }

        public interface Listener {

            void onLoaded(Object product);

            void onError();
        }

        private com.learn2crack.listviewjson.LoadJSONTaskProduct.Listener mListener;

        @Override
        protected ResponseProduct doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try {

                String stringResponse =loadJSON(strings[0]);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
Log.e("TESTLOGTaskProd2",stringResponse);

                return  gson.fromJson(stringResponse, ResponseProduct.class);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ResponseProduct response) {

            if (response != null) {

                mListener.onLoaded(response.getProduct());

            } else {

                mListener.onError();
            }
        }

        private String loadJSON(String jsonURL) throws IOException {

            URL url = new URL(jsonURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            Log.e("TESTLOG11",in.toString());
            String line;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            Log.e("TESTLOG22",response.toString());
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                response.append(line);
            }

            in.close();
            Log.e("TESTLOG23",response.toString());
            return response.toString();
        }
    }
```

My LoadJSONTaskProduct.java

---

```
    package com.learn2crack.listviewjson;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.learn2crack.listviewjson.model.ProductDetails;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
public class ShowProductDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements LoadJSONTaskProduct.Listener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{


    private ListView mListView;

Object product;

    //http://copy-cat.at/api/index.php?act=getProduct&product_id=
    //public static final String URL = "http://copy-cat.at/api/index.php?act=getProduct&product_id=118";

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> mProductMapList = new ArrayList<>();


    private static final String KEY_VER = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_API = "permalink";
    private static final String KEY_SRC = "src";
    private static final String KEY_REGPRICE = "regular_price";
    private static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_product_details);

        String productid = getIntent().getStringExtra("productid");

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);


       Log.e("TESTLOGPRODUCT", productid);
//http://copy-cat.at/api/index.php?act=getProduct&product_id=
     String URLRequest = "http://copy-cat.at/api/index.php?act=getProduct&product_id="+productid;

            new LoadJSONTaskProduct(this).execute(URLRequest);


    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(Object product ) {
        //Log.e("TESTLOGPRODUCT2", product.toString());
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String splittString = product.toString();
        String[] split = splittString.split(",",-1);
        Log.e("TESTLOGPRODUCT2", split.toString());
        /**       JSONArray json;

        Object myjson = new JSONObject(product);
        JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("profiles");

        json = product;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("interests");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
            list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("interestKey"));
        }
            map.put(KEY_VER, product.toString());
           // map.put(KEY_TITLE, product.getTitle());


            mProductMapList.add(map);

**/

      loadListView();

    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        Toast.makeText(this, mProductMapList.get(i).get(KEY_TITLE),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //ShowProduct.getProduct(this);
    }

    private void loadListView() {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ShowProductDetails.this, mProductMapList, R.layout.content_show_product_details,
                new String[] { KEY_VER},
                new int[] { R.id.id});

        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



}
```

My ShowProductDetails.class (Main File - Activity)

Comment: Your API OUTPUT JSON is giving you a JSON Object but you are taking it as a JSON Array.

Comment: Ok im a newbie... JSONObject product; and public JSONObject getProduct() now working...

Comment: you don't tell us how you are loading that json.

Comment: private Object product;

    public Object getProduct() {
        Log.e("TESTLOGT2dddd",product.toString());
        return product;
    }

Returns the result

{title=Camera DS, id=590.0, ....

Same with  private JSONObject product;

Result is empty....